# Giving certain users access to certain clients in IdentityServer3

Tags: restriction, identityserver3

Is there any way using IdentityServer v3 to give a user access to a client but restrict it to another.  I know I can make my own table in the database to handle this, but I was wondering if anything like this has been created in IdentityServer3 already?